# Can't edit Customer information on Account Dashboard

Tags: magento2, customer-account, dashboard, edit

I dont get this Edit option on Account dashboard page in my magento 2.3
See **https://prnt.sc/r0n52s**
I am not getting this in my website.
Is there any configuration for this?

Thanks.

Comment: It comes by default, maybe it is removed by some custom module.

Comment: ^ or template update. Maybe turn on template hints - see if there is any customisation